# Extracting an rpm package and assigning the output to a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I want to extract an rpm package without installing it and my command is:

```
$ rpm2cpio ./packagecloud-test-1.1-1.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv
./usr/local/bin/packagecloud_hello.zip
17 block
```

Now I want to assign this `./usr/local/bin/packagecloud_hello.zip` to a variable in order to navigate to that particular directory. Could anyone please help me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```
$ var=$(rpm2cpio ./packagecloud-test-1.1-1.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv | head -1  | sed 's,^\.,,')
$ echo $var
/usr/local/bin/packagecloud_hello.zip
```

However, `/usr/local/bin/packagecloud_hello.zip` does not like a
directory name, it's most probably a file name.  To remove a file name part:

```
$ dirname $var
/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: $ echo $var is returning nothing

Comment: [aem@slh-fra02-mmgmgmt-deploy9901 Author]$ var=$(rpm2cpio ./mamcom-assets-infrastructure-aem6-release-1.2.0.rpm | cpio -idmv | head -1  | sed 's,^\.,,')
./mmg/adobe/aem/packages/mamcom-assets-complete-package-1.2.0.zip
434 blocks
[aem@slh-fra02-mmgmgmt-deploy9901 Author]$ echo $var

[aem@slh-fra02-mmgmgmt-deploy9901 Author]$

Comment: Does `rpm2cpio ./mamcom-assets-infrastructure-aem6-release-1.2.0.rpm | cpio -idmv` itself print anything?

Comment: yes it prints 
./mmg/adobe/aem/packages/mamma-complete-package-3.0.0.zip
5999 blocks